# Using laravel queues/jobs on different apps, need advice

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have different repositories for web and backend batch/jobs with laravel apps on them. This is for scaling easier, and safer releases. I dont want changes on some backend batch process to affect anything on the web part.

I cannot use laravel queues and jobs for dispatching jobs from the web part, because the queue worker would be on the batch server with a different laravel app.

What is the recommended way to deal with this kind of setup? Currently I am thinking of a combination of redis [pub/sub](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis#pubsub) and laravel queues on the backend. So I will need 2 supervisors, one for subscribe command and one for queue worker. There are a few issues with redis sbuscribe, such as restarting the supervisor on new deployment, I might lose some published messages. A workaround could be using pm2 rolling restart though.

But I wonder if there is any other better approach or package for laravel to deal with my use case?

Comment: I would definitely be using redis to store queued jobs. You can dispatch to them via any server and it means all your jobs would be going to the same place to be run.

Comment: @Savlon but that only works if all servers have the same app/code deployed right? I have 2 different apps of laravel though (different repos, different code).

Answer (score 2):

In the end I found I could do:

web repo - app 1:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
...

class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $userId;
    private $someParam;

    public function __construct(int $userId, string $someParam)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->someParam = $someParam;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // for implementation check same file in batch repo
    }
}
```

batch repo - app 2

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;
...

class SomeJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $userId;
    private $someParam;

    public function __construct(int $userId, string $someParam)
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;
        $this->someParam = $someParam;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        // actual implementation
        echo $this->userId . " " . $this->someParam;
    }
}
```

Then I can do in web app:

```
SomeJob::dispatch($userId, $someParam);
```

And in batch app have a running queue worker:

```
php artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=1 --delay=1
```

And works just fine, gets processed on batch server. I am using redis to store the queued job.

Explanation:

The way it works is that when I dispatch a job on web app, it creates a key in redis with the name of the Job (classname and filepath), and the constructor parameters I passed, all this is stored in redis.

Then on batch when I run the queue worker, it gets all the queued keys and searches for the same file and path, so they have to be identical. Then it will start up the actual implementation on the batch repo.

This even works with different versions of laravel. I have version 8 on app and version 5.7 on batch and works just fine.